# Transformation of variables in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find $n$ such that the substitution $y=zx^n$ transforms the differential equation

$x^2y''+2x(x+2)y'+2(x+1)^2y=\cos{x}$

into one with constant coefficients. Hence solve the original equation, and show that in all solutions, $y$ is small when $x$ is large and positive.

Required to obtain new equation in$z$ and $x$.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=nzx^{n-1}+x^n\frac{dz}{dx}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=n[(n-1)x^{n-2}z+x^{n-1}\frac{dz}{dx}]+[x^n \frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+nx^{n-1}\frac{dz}{dx}]$

Substituting

$x^2[n(n-1)x^{n-2}z+2nx^{n-1}\frac{dz}{dx}+x^n \frac{d^2z}{dt^2}]$

$+2x(x+2)[nzx^{n-1}+x^n \frac{dz}{dx}]$

$+2(x+1)^2[zx^n]=\cos{x}$

New differential

$x^{n+2}\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+\frac{dz}{dx}[2nx^{n+1}+2x^{n+1}(x+2)]+nz(n-1)x^n+2nx^nz(x+2)+2zx^n(x^2+2x+1)=\cos{x}$

$\rightarrow n=-2$

$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+2\frac{dz}{dx}+[8z-\frac{6}{x^2}z]=\cos{x}$

The equation is supposed to be

$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+2\frac{dz}{dx}+2z=\cos{x}$

Comment: Did you mean $d^2z/dt^2$ or $d^2y/dx^2$?

Comment: @MrYouMath, it was a typo error. I edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=nzx^{n-1}+x^n\frac{dz}{dx}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=n[(n-1)x^{n-2}z+x^{n-1}\frac{dz}{dx}]+[x^n \frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+nx^{n-1}\frac{dz}{dx}]$

Substituting

$x^2[zn(n-1)x^{n-2}+2nx^{n-1}\frac{dz}{dx}+x^n \frac{d^2z}{dt^2}]$

$+2x(x+2)[nzx^{n-1}+x^n \frac{dz}{dx}]$

$+2(x+1)^2[zx^n]=\cos{x}$

New differential

$x^{n+2}\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+\frac{dz}{dx}[2nx^{n+1}+2x(x+2)x^n]+nz(n-1)x^n+2nzx^n(x+2)+2zx^n(x^2+2x+1)=\cos{x}$

$\rightarrow n=-2$

$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+\frac{dz}{dx}[-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{2}{x}(x+2)]+\frac{(z)(-2)(-3)}{x^2}-4(x+2)\frac{z}{x^2}+2(x^2+2x+1)\frac{z}{x^2}=\cos{x}$

$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+2\frac{dz}{dx}+2z=\cos{x}$

A.E

$m^2+2m+2=0$

$m=-1±i$

$z=e^{-t}(A \cos{x}+ B \sin{x})$

P.S

$z=\frac{\cos{x}}{D^2+2D+2}=(2D-1)\frac{\cos{x}}{2D-1}=\frac{1}{5}(2\sin{x}+\cos{x})$

Since $y=zx^n=\frac{z}{x^2}$

$y=\frac{1}{x^2}[\frac{\cos{x}}{D^2+2D+2}=(2D-1)\frac{\cos{x}}{2D-1}=\frac{1}{5}(2\sin{x}+\cos{x})]$

As $x\rightarrow \infty, y\rightarrow 0 $

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{n+2}\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+\frac{dz}{dx}[2nx^{n+1}+2x^{n+1}(x+2)]+nz(n-1)x^n+2nx^nz(x+2)+2zx^n(x^2+2x+1)={\cos(x)}$$
$n=-2$
$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+\frac{dz}{dx}[-4x^{-1}+2x^{-1}(x+2)]-2z(-3)x^{-2}-4x^{-2}z(x+2)+2zx^{-2}(x^2+2x+1)={\cos(x)}$$

$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+2\frac{dz}{dx} +6x^{-2}z -4x^{-1}z-8x^{-2}z +2z+4x^{-1}z+2x^{-2}z ={\cos(x)}$$
$6x^{-2}z-4x^{-1}z-8x^{-2}z +2z+4x^{-1}z+2x^{-2}z=2z$
$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+2\frac{dz}{dx} +2z ={\cos(x)}$$